# pyparsing OneOrMore().asxml() tags are not correct

Tags: python, pyparsing

when i use asXML() to output a ParsedResults as xml the tags sometimes do not match what i have specified in setResultsName().

example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
from pyparsing import *

mystring="""
a b c
x y z
"""
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(" \t\r")
SOL = LineStart().leaveWhitespace().suppress()
EOL = LineEnd().suppress()

first = SOL + Word(alphas)('first')
second = Word(alphas)('second')
third = Word(alphas)('third') + EOL
line = Group(first + second + third).setResultsName('line')

print OneOrMore(line).setResultsName('mylines').searchString(mystring).asXML()
```

and this is my output

```xml
<ITEM>
  <mylines>
    <mylines>
      <first>a</first>
      <second>b</second>
      <third>c</third>
    </mylines>
    <line>
      <first>x</first>
      <second>y</second>
      <third>z</third>
    </line>
  </mylines>
</ITEM>
```

why is there one mylines tag nested in another at the top but then the next block is a line tag like i was expecting ?

Comment: This is a bug in asXML().